# Add row functionality in AngularJS table similar to Microsoft Word tables

Tags: angularjs

When we hover our mouse between two rows of a Microsoft Office word table.
It displays a "+" icon, clicking on it inserts a new row in that table.
I want to achieve the same functionality with AngularJS with in a HTML table.

example:

```
         --------------------
          Row   1 | Value
         -------------------<"+" Icon>
          Row   2 | Value
         --------------------
```

In most cases we have an Icon with each row which enables us to Add a row  just below it.But then user will not be able to add row just below the header.

I found the Microsoft Word way very user friendly,so,I am interested in adding that feature in HTML table with AngularJS.

```
<table>    
    <tr ng-repeat="step in steps">
               <td>{{ step.name }}</td>
               <td>{{ step.description }}</td>
               <td><button ng-click="addRow($index)">Add</button></td>
   </tr>
</table>

   $scope.addRow = function(index) {
       // Code
           $scope.steps.splice(index+1,1,{  step.name :"" , step.descrption:""})
       //Code 
}
```

Comment: This is ***incredibly*** broad.  Do you have anything for us to work off of?  Did you write any code in motivation of this goal?

Comment: Hi , I added a code snippet which shows usual functionality we have.

Comment: This is not really broad, the functionality is already implemented, the question is how to add the behavior of adding a row on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just add a header row and a special button with the following?

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td class="add-row"><button ng-click="addRow(-1)">Add</button></td>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

(I added a class to that td just to be able to position it out of the table flow...)

Comment: Thanks rewritten. Can you please post the code for add-row class.

Comment: .add-row {
    position: relative;
    top: -18px;
    left: 18px;
}
This will add the icon on top right corner.